# Any example of a transaction where `feeRecipient` is used in 0x

Tags: transactions, etherscan, 0x, fees

I need to see what these transactions look like on Etherscan, but can't find any examples. Seems to be very rare. Some transaction hash of such transaction where `feeRecipient` is receiving some small chunk of the swap will be helpful. Thanks!